# drop-shadow and rotation css behavior on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, filter, transform

Something is wrong when I use filter: drop-shadow 
and transform: rotate(##deg)

I've attached an image and a url so you can see for yourself

Note that it happened on chrome.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent this?

[url to follow](http://www.facegift.co.il/canvas/print.aspx?pagenum=1&width=1000&print=2&userItemId=53043&Sc=949008&test=on)

[image: image preview]

```css
.wrap1,
.wrap2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%
}
.wrap1 {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4) 10px 10px 10px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5.696863186209043deg);
  filter: drop-shadow(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4) 10px 10px 10px);
  transform: rotate(5.696863186209043deg);
  left: 0;
}
.wrap2 {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4) 10px 10px 10px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  filter: drop-shadow(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4) 10px 10px 10px);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  left: 50%;
}
.inner,
.inner_color {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner img {
  width: 100%;
}
.inner_color {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap1">
  <div class="inner_color"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://www.facegift.co.il/PrivateData/Images/15152/1515293_M.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap2">
  <div class="inner_color"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://www.facegift.co.il/PrivateData/Images/15152/1515293_M.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you shear your running code? So we can check what's going on there?

Comment: thanks @Husain Ahmmed, Ive added a url, I it good enough?

Comment: ok, ive added a code. thank you for you comment @Paulie_D

Comment: Unable to replicate and your code does not show this issue - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WGAEEV Chrome Version 54.0.2840.16 beta-m (64-bit)

Comment: althought its not been reproduced, you can still see on the snippet there is a difference between .wrap1 and .wrap2 one is not shown, and the other is. and the only difference on the css is the rotation value. if you set the rotation to 0, you will see the image. @Paulie_D

Comment: and my Chrome version is this : 53.0.2785.101 m (64-bit) and it say its uptodate

Comment: @Paulie_D You don't see it in beta, but I can see it in 53.0.2785. This probably is a bug in v 53 that has been fixed

Comment: Seems to be okay for me at Chrome version  `Version 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit)` ; Better not delve into browser version of Chrome, try Safari!

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be a bug of the current release of Chrome (the stable release).

You can fix it rotating the inner elements instead of the element with the filter:

```css
.wrap1,
.wrap2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%
}
.wrap1 {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4) 10px 10px 10px);
  filter: drop-shadow(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4) 10px 10px 10px);
  left: 0;
}

/* the transform is applied to descendats of the wrap1 instead */
.wrap1 div {
  transform: rotate(5.696863186209043deg);
}

.wrap2 {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4) 10px 10px 10px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  filter: drop-shadow(rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4) 10px 10px 10px);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  left: 50%;
}
.inner,
.inner_color {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner img {
  width: 100%;
}
.inner_color {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap1">
  <div class="inner_color"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://www.facegift.co.il/PrivateData/Images/15152/1515293_M.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap2">
  <div class="inner_color"></div>
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://www.facegift.co.il/PrivateData/Images/15152/1515293_M.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it renders fine in Canary.  I switched almost a month ago now due to weird rendering issues in the normal Chrome releases.  Every other time starting the browser I'd even get an all black viewport with gray boxes in the corners.  I tried all the various fixes up to and including wiping it all out and making a new profile, but nothing fixed it.  Using Canary and Yandex now with no issues.